Vanishing curvature of nonlinear connection $\Leftrightarrow$ path-independent parallel transport
I'm trying to figure out if the following claim is true:

A (nonlinear) connection on a fiber bundle is flat if and only if the
corresponding parallel transport is path-independent.

I intuitively think that this holds (and it is also claimed to be true here) but I can't come up with a complete proof. The bottleneck seems to be the application of the Frobenius theorem.
My idea (for the implication to the right) is the following. We define a (nonlinear) connection on a vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ by means of a horizontal lift operator $\mathfrak{X}(M)\ni X_p\mapsto X_p^h \in \mathfrak{X}(E)$, leading to a direct sum $TE = HE \oplus VE$ in terms of a horizontal bundle $HE$ (the 'image' of the horizontal lift operator) and the vertical bundle $VE$, canonically defined as $VE = \text{ker}(\pi)$.
The connection is said to be flat if its curvature $[X^h, Y^h] - [X,Y]^h$ vanishes for all vector fields $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$. This condition is equivalent to the statement that the horizontal distribution $HE$ is involutive. Hence it is integrable, by Frobenius' theorem. It is claimed here that this implies that parallel transport is path-independent. I don't follow this last implication.
To me, what Frobenius' theorem tells us is that we can find local coordinates $\{x^i\}_{i=1,\dots, n+k}$ on $E$, where $n = \dim M$ and $k =$rank$(E)$, such that $HE$ is given locally by $HE = \text{span}(\partial_{x^1}, \dots, \partial_{x^n})$. Now, parallel transport of a vector $v_0\in E$ along a curve $\gamma$ in $M$ is given by the unique curve $v$ in $E$ characterized by the requirements that $v(t=0)=v_0$, $\dot v\in HE$ and $\pi\circ v = \gamma$. So path-independence of parallel transport (or equivalently, the statement that parallel transport over a loop returns the original vector) comes down to the statement that if $\gamma$ is a loop, then any such curve $v$ must also be a loop. I don't see how the result of Frobenius' theorem implies such a thing. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, the result is not true in general.  For paths that are not homotopic one can indeed construct counterexamples. Consider e.g. the Möbius strip with standard flat linear connection. Then parallel transporting an 'upward' pointing vector exactly once around the strip may result in a 'downward' pointing vector.
So far I managed to prove under a (significant) additional assumption that flatness is equivalent to path independence of parallel transport along homotopic piecewise smooth curves. The additional assumption here is that parallel should be well-defined along any curve (for any finite parameter time). Still, I would very much like to figure out if the result also holds without this assumption.

Because any horizontal lift gives a curve $\tilde\gamma\subset E$ projecting to $\gamma$ and lying in the unique integral manifold containing the initial "value" $v_0\in E$.

I should add that it's important, of course, that the integral manifolds are all $n$-dimensional.

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate on how this implies that parallel transport is path-independent?

We should have specified that the path independence holds only locally (i.e., closed paths that are not nullhomotopic may yield different results). The integral manifolds locally project diffeomorphically to $M$.

Under the additional assumption that the connection is smooth and its parallel transport map is well-defined (for any parameter time) along any curve, the result below can be proven. The latter is true for linear connections, for instance, but not necessarily for nonlinear ones. I don't know whether the result can be extended to the fully generic case.

The connection is flat if and only if parallel transport is homotopically path-independent.

Here homotopic path independence means that if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$  are two homotopic piecewise smooth curves from $p\in M$ to $q\in M$ and $v$ is a vector in $E_p$, then parallel transport of $v$ along $\gamma_1$ yields the same result as parallel transport of $v$ along $\gamma_2$.
Proof sketch. We focus on the implication to the right. First note that flatness is equivalent to having an involutive, hence (by Frobenius) integrable horizontal bundle, i.e. there exists a foliation $\cup_\alpha \mathcal L_\alpha$ of $E$ such that $HE$ is given locally as the tangent space $T\mathcal L_\alpha$ to one of the leaves $\mathcal L_\alpha$.
Consider two homotopic smooth (not just piecewise smooth; this comes later) curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ in $M$ from $p$ to $q$ and suppose for contradiction that some $v\in E_p$ is parallel transported to $v_1
\neq v_2\in E_q$ along the two curves, respectively. By a standard result, there exists a smooth homotopy from $\gamma_1 $ to $\gamma_2$. We can now parallel transport $v$ over any intermediate curve $\gamma_s$ in this homotopy, where $s\in [1,2]$. Since the connection is smooth, parallel transport is given by a sufficiently nice ODE whose solutions depend smoothly on $s$. We thus obtain a smooth curve $\eta:[1,2]\to E$ consisting of the end results of the parallel transport. The image of this curve lies in $E_q$ and we have $\eta(1)=v_1$ and $\eta(2)=v_2$.
We now show that $\dot\eta\neq 0$ is both horizontal and vertical, a contradiction.
Horizontality: For each $s$, the vector $\eta(s)$ can be obtained by parallel transporting $v$. Equivalently, there exists a horizontal curve from $v$ to $\eta(s)$. Since locally $HE = T\mathcal L_\alpha$, this implies that all $\eta(s)$ must lie in a single leaf $\mathcal L_\alpha$ of the foliation. By a standard result, the leaves are weakly embedded in $E$, meaning that $\eta$ is also smooth as a curve $\eta:[1,2]\to \mathcal L_\alpha$. But then $\dot\eta\in T\mathcal L_\alpha = HE$.
Verticality: This is trivial, since the base point $q$ is constant along the curve. Applying some basic definitions yields $\dot\eta \in \ker \text{d}\pi = VE$.
This is a contradiction, hence parallel transport along two smooth curves yields the same. Now in general, if we have a piecewise smooth curve, we can always smoothen it (homotopically) in such a way that at the beginning and end of each segment, the smooth curve intersects the original curve. (This can be shown in a chart around a cusp, using bump functions.) Since each segment is smooth, parallel transport over any segment of the original curve agrees with parallel transport over the corresponding segment of the smoothened curve, and hence this is also true for the complete curves. Given two homotopic piecewise smooth curves, we can thus show that their parallel transport maps agree by comparing them to the parallel transport maps along their smoothened versions.
